# Should I tell the recruiter I'm being used as a subcontractor?

Tags: contracts

I've got a bad sense for these types of things. I recruiting agency hired me for a short term job (less than a month long). On the paper work I'm an employee of the agency. Their client is actually a managed IT firm. In actuality, I have almost nothing to do with the managed IT firm (or the recruiting agency) and I report to the manager at the managed IT firm's client and work at their site. Should I tell the recruiter this? I don't think she's actually very technical and knows what a managed IT firm is. Should I tell her that I'm basically a subcontractor? I don't really see this mattering to them and could only have the potential to cause a negative outcome.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow who this recruiter is. Do you work for a temp agency and your recruiter is the person who finds you jobs to report to? In which case she should already know you're not an employee of the IT firm.

Comment: I don't see a problem that needs fixing. You're an employee of a recruiting company. They put you on with one of their clients, which happens to be an MSP. They in turn have you working with one of their clients. I've been in exactly the same situation. There's nothing illegal, unorthodox, or untoward here. What is your actual concern?

Comment: What is the problem here? Subcontracting is a perfectly legitimate thing. The managed IT firm is either paying your agency more than they would an internal employee. And if they're not; you can't blame them for outsourcing the work either. Tell or don't tell; what problem are you trying to solve? "Should I" is generally not a productive question to ask here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I tell the recruiter this?

You could if you like.

I'd be surprised if the agency doesn't already know. (What the specific recruiter knows is irrelevant).

And I'd be more surprised if it mattered to anyone, as long as everyone gets paid.

Comment: If you are uncomfortable you can ask about it, more than likely they already know!

Comment: I was surprised the agency new this and didn't tell me.

Answer (score -2):

To a headhunting recruiter, it depends.

To a Hiring Manager / HR Recruiter of the company, yes.

In the event if it's the second, for South East Asia (Singapore) it is recommended to clearly state both in your CV and in interview that you are hired by XXX Consulting Agency and was seconded to YYY company as IT/Engineering Consultant throughout the entirety of your previous employment.

Doing so helps to avoid any potential misunderstandings if the recruiting company runs a background check on you and found out that your payroll was under that agency which employs you.

### Good luck!

Edit: Added Answer's country of origin for better context :)

Comment: Most people reading your CV aren't interested in the precise details of your contractual arrangements, they want to know what you did and for whom.

Comment: Thanks for your input but I beg to differ sir. From where I came from IT Consulting is the norm and there is a big difference between stating yourselves to be a permanent employee of Microsoft VS a permanent employee of Accenture being seconded to Microsoft as a IT Consultant/ Engineering Contractor for example. (PS: I'm from Singapore)